# Cleaning to rid house of cat allergen after cat is gone

Tags: allergy, removal, environmental-climate, animal-dander, detergent

We discovered through a blood test that our 3yo is severely allergic to cats. We have two cats who are 7 and 8 respectively and we're adopted as kittens. So their hair and dander is all over everything in our house. We are finding new homes for that cats, but I have the painstaking chore of cleaning their hair and dander off/out of everything in the house. I know it will take a while to really clean the house and it will never be entirely free of all hair.

Forgive me if this isn't the right place to ask (maybe the biology SE?), but I am trying to figure out the best way to clean so the allergen is dead or denatured so it does not affect my daughter. Will washing clothes and other linens in very hot water kill whatever it is in the hair and dander that causes a reaction? So that even if the hair is present, it won't affect her? Is there a kind of soap or other agent I can use?

Fortunately, we have no carpeting in the house, but we do have rugs. And since we live in a cold climate, we also have lots of thick, heavy blankets of various textiles and materials.

Comment: Has your daughter shown symptoms of cat allergy before? Maybe there is no need to give away 2 family cats if the allergic reaction has not occurred in 3 years.

Comment: She has terrible eczema that we've been treating for a while. Her doctor said it might be an allergic reaction so he ordered a blood test and confirmed the allergy to cats (as well as dogs, incidentally). If she had no reaction, we wouldn't bother. But she's terribly uncomfortable and I don't want to have to give her a daily medication for her to be comfortable in her own home just so we can keep the cats.

Comment: I understand. I don't have experience with this so I can't help you, sadly. Maybe ask your doctor directly?